# Update value not incrementing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

I am trying to increment a value by one each time but its not working. My variable `currentValue` gives me `0` as expected but when i try increment it using `var newValue = currentValue ++;` it still gives me `0`.

```
function updateClicks(e, maxValue) {
    var buttonClicked = e.target;
    addClass("clicked", buttonClicked);
    var counterBox = buttonClicked.nextElementSibling;

    var currentValue = buttonClicked.value;
    console.log(currentValue);

    var newValue = currentValue++;
    console.log(newValue);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `newValue = currentValue++` effectively does: `newValue = currentValue; currentValue = currentValue + 1;`. Try `newValue = ++currentValue;`, or just `newValue = currentValue + 1` if you don't actually want to change `currentValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to affect the incremented value you have to use `pre increment` operator like :

```
var newValue = ++currentValue;
```

Since `currentValue++` (post increment) will increment the `currentValue` but after assigning it to the `newValue` variable.

- **`pre-increment`** : (`++currentValue`) will adds one to the value of `currentValue` then returns `currentValue`.
- **`post-increment`** : (`currentValue++`) will returns `currentValue` then adds one to it.

Hope this helps.

```js
var currentValue = 0;
console.log('Increment using pre increment : '+(++currentValue));
console.log('pre increment return : '+currentValue);

console.log('-----------------------------------');

var currentValue = 0;
console.log('Increment using post increment : '+(currentValue++));
console.log('post increment return : '+currentValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will give you 0 for first time. **Why ?**
**++** `(post increment)` operator - returns the value **then** increments it's value.
Example

```
var a = 4;
var b = a++; // Here it assigns 4 to b, then increments it's value
console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 4
```

You must use the `pre increment` form

```
  var a = 4;
  var b = ++a; // Here it increments it's value then assigns it to b
  console.log(a); // 5
  console.log(b); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var newValue = ++currentValue;
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how will this help?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!